# Disable WordPress 5.5 plugin emails

Tags: wordpress

How do we disable emails about Wordpress 5.5’s new email notifications saying that plugins are up to date or out of date? I’ve made many sites and these emails are annoying.

Looking for some code to add to functions.php. Not a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I think this will work.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/controlling-plugin-and-theme-auto-update-email-notifications-and-site-health-infos-in-wp-5-5/

```
// Disable auto-update email notifications for plugins.
add_filter( 'auto_plugin_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
 
// Disable auto-update email notifications for themes.
add_filter( 'auto_theme_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: if you want to disable the core update notifications as well, use this: ```add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );```